# Matching json values in an array using spring restdocs in random order

Tags: json, spring, rest, jsonpath, spring-restdocs

I am using Spring RestDocs to validate my REST APIs.

One API is returning an array of generated values based on some input. I want to verify that the generated values in the response are correct.

A response could be:

```
{ "hybrids": ["horsephant", "pussydog", "tigerbird"]
```

Since the order of the values is not relevant, the next call to the API could result in:

```
{ "hybrids": ["pussydog", "horsedonkey", "tigerbird"]
```

I am using the following snippet in my RestDoc test:

```
.jsonPath("$.hybrids[0]").isEqualTo("pussydog")             .jsonPath("$.hybrids[1]").isEqualTo("horsedonkey")              .jsonPath("$.hybrids[2]").isEqualTo("tigerbird");
```

This only results in a pass when the order is accidently like that. How can I remove the order of the items and have both responses result in a pass of the test?

Thanks